# Code Pascal applications on Android phone

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-7, pascal, mobile-phones

I have problems with computer right now and that's why I can't build applications. So I want to code them atleast on Android and compile on computer.

**Is there any Delphi or Pascal developer program for Android 2.2.1?**

Comment: I guess you know a search engine that you can use, right? Anyway, do you think it is comfortable to program on the softkeyboard on an android device?

Comment: -1 Please don't change the meaning of your question via edits, that makes some answers useless and reduces the overall quality of the question for other users who come here (e.g. by search engines). Rather invest a few minutes to write a clear question from the beginning.

Comment: You just need a text editor for your phone.

Comment: @David Heffernan I agree with you. I would love to have a text editor on my phone.

Comment: you need to root your phone, then compile the free pascal compiler for ARM, and, if you get this far, you know what to do (:

Comment: Also if you root your phone, you can use vi within the Android Terminal Emulator.
https://market.android.com/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en

Comment: I failed to root my phone. :(

Comment: I really don't think that you want to root your phone!

Comment: I don't know about you, but I need a full-sized keyboard in order to code anything.

Answer (score 2):

[RemObjects just released Oxygene For Java](http://www.delphifeeds.com/go/s/86772), a JVM-targetted version of their Oxygene dialect of Object Pascal.  It's basically a port of Delphi Prism to target JVMs (including Android devices) instead of .NET.  It's not exactly Delphi, but it's fairly close.

Comment: I dont want to be rude but I'm trying to code Pascal language on mobile phone!

Comment: @Roberts: Oh, you want to do the coding *on* the mobile phone?  Can't help you then...

Comment: I know this is not an answer, but Delphi XE2 was just released, which includes the ability to code mobile applications using Delphi :D as well as applications for Mac, AND 64bit :P

Answer (score 0):

The Free Pascal compiler has now been compiled for Android and packaged as an Android app called [PascalGUI](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.n0n3m4.droidpascal&hl=en), which includes a simple, low-functioning IDE.  I've used it to compile some Free Pascal command-line applications I wrote on Windows and Linux, and it works very, very well.

Again, it's not Delphi exactly, but it's close, and it works well for me on my phone with or without a Bluetooth keyboard.